# python multiplication precision

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, precision

I am trying something relatively simple in python3

```
fx = 2400/5.52
ifx = 1/fx

124*ifx*fx
```

gives
`124.00000000000001`

This creates a real problem is above is multiplied by -1 and floored

I have tried using numpy float also but get the same result
(BTw the answer above is not a print statement, just exec in python3 shell)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function that will return the closest integer, rather than ceil or floor. Here is what I use for that type of issues:

```
def proper_integer(x):
    """Function used to make sure that 1.0/1.0 = int(1), not float(1.0000000000000001)."""

    distances = []
    for n in (-2, -1, 0, +1, +2):
        xi = int(np.floor(x)) + n
        d = abs(x-xi)
        distances.append((d, n))

    n_closest = min(distances)[1] # The n that corresponds to the min d.
    return int(np.floor(x)) + n_closest
```

Basically, it rounds the number down using `np.floor(x)` and checks whether adding a small integer from -2 to +2 gets the result closer to what you would expect.

In your case, `proper_integer(124*ifx*fx)` should return exactly `124`.

Comment: Thanks, but running a ```for``` for every integer in an array seems wasteful?

Comment: It's not every integer, it's just the needed ones. For me the performance is fine since I don't call this function on a lot of data but just on one number. You can make it faster with a list comprehension, but then it would become ugly to read: `distances = [(abs(x - int(np.floor(x)) + n), n) for n in (-2, -1, 0, +1, +2)]`.

Comment: Iterating through `(-1, 0, +1)` might be enough now that you say it.